# I want to integrate Extentreports with HTML Reports

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to  generate customized extentreports by integrating extentreports with html reports.I need to modify UI of ExtentReports but I am not able to find the location in a code where I want to change in.I have decomplied the jars aswell. Please tell me how do I find the location.

Comment: Use the github source code instead of decompiling jars. https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/tree/master/src. A lot of the UI can be modified by using API itself.

Comment: I have searched API but couldn't find ,Where will i get Extent Report API to modify UI.